# MySQL list all duplicates on a specific field and only if day between another field date <= 1 and with a complex criteria

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in MySQL "mytable" like this :

```
    id    car_num      date  
    -----  --------   -----------
    00001    BBB      2015-09-28
    00002    BBB      2015-10-04
    00003    DDD      2015-10-04
    00004    BBB      2015-10-04
    00005    AAA      2015-10-05
    00006    GGG      2015-10-05
    00007    GGG      2015-10-05
    00009    EEE      2015-10-06
    00010    AAA      2015-10-06
    00011    HHH      2015-10-10
    00012    FFF      2015-10-11
    00013    FFF      2015-10-11
    00014    CCC      2015-10-13
```

I want to display duplicates (on field car_num) only if there is less or equal than 1 day between date fields for each couple of duplicates and I want to order them by date DESC

What I expect :

```
     id    car_num      date  
    -----  --------   -----------
    00012    FFF      2015-10-11
    00013    FFF      2015-10-11
    00010    AAA      2015-10-06
    00005    AAA      2015-10-05
    00006    GGG      2015-10-05
    00007    GGG      2015-10-05
    00002    BBB      2015-10-04
    00004    BBB      2015-10-04
```

I had asked this question here : [MySQL list all duplicates on a specific field and only if day between another field date <= 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34047731/mysql-list-all-duplicates-on-a-specific-field-and-only-if-day-between-another-fi)

The last answer solved my problem :

```
select t.* from mytable t where exists (select 1
          from mytable t2
          where t.car_num = t2.car_num and 
                t.id <> t2.id and
                abs(datediff(t2.date, t.date)) <= 1
         );
```

Now I want to apply the same query with a more complex criteria, the previous request works if the clause WHERE is simply "where t.car_num = t2.car_num" but now I want to compare on more complex criteria like this : UPPER(REPLACE(REPLACE(car_num , ' ', '') , '-', '')) not directly ON car_num. I try to pass param with a function "where reduce_num(t.car_num)=reduce_num(t2.car_num)" but query enters into infinite loop. Any idea ?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: That question is nearly a year old and it's asked by you !.Looks like you are upgrading your inventory software ,anyway can you explain a bit more of your complex criteria

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your functions on the field car_num in seperate SELECT-statements, like this:

```
select t.* from 
(
    select *, replace(replace(car_num,' ',''),'-','') reduce_num from mytable
) t 
where exists 
    (
    select 1 from 
    (
    select *, replace(replace(car_num,' ',''),'-','') reduce_num from mytable
 ) t2
 where (t.reduce_num = t2.reduce_num) and 
    (t.id <> t2.id) and
    (abs(datediff(t2.datum, t.datum)) <= 1)
     );
```

Comment: Thanks Rick, your solution works perfectly. Problem solved.